Logcat panel in Android Studio has no toolbars or tabs
I am running Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1 Patch 1.
When viewing the logcat panel there are absolutely no toolbars, tabs or logs.  The panel just says "Nothing to show" and clicking the New Tab "+" button does nothing.
Running "adb logcat" on the command line works just fine.
Anybody know how to fix this so I can see the log in Android Studio?

I have tried restarting Android Studio and undocking the Logcat View.
Update:
Suddenly this morning, it is working just fine.  All I did yesterday was shut it down and then start it back up this morning.  I didn't even reboot my laptop.  No idea why it's working now.

